# How can I remove some element in List with Immutable?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I use react + redux with Immutable, and how can I remove some element in List with Immutable?

```
import Immutable, { List, Map, fromJS } from 'immutable';

let initialState = fromJS({
    floor: [
        {
            floor: '1',
            rooms: [
                {
                    room: '101'
                },
                {
                    room: '102'
                },
                {
                    room: '103'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

export default function list(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        //remove some room
        case REMOVE_ROOM:
            //how can I remove some element in List with Immutable?
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

then, I dispatch a action that remove some room with `dispatch(removeRoom('102'))`, but how can I simply to remove `{room: 102}` with Immutable?

Comment: I would recommend you to keep your state flat. If you had list of rooms and floors as a separate key in the state, then it would be much easier for you to deal with data. Check out this library https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, write a function `findRoomPath` to find room path in your state.

And use `deleteIn` to remove the value at this path.

```
var roomPath = findRoomPath(state, 101);
state = state.deleteIn(roomPath);
```

```js
var state = Immutable.fromJS({
    floor: [
        {
            floor: '1',
            rooms: [
                {
                    room: '101'
                }
            ]
        },
      {
            floor: '2',
            rooms: [
                {
                    room: '104'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

function findRoomPath(state, room) {
  var keyPath = ['floor'];
  state
    .get('floor')
    .find((v, k1) => {
      return v
        .get('rooms')
        .find(function(v, k2) {
          if (+v.get('room') === +room) {
            keyPath.push(k1, 'rooms', k2);
            return true;
          }
        });
    
    });

  return keyPath.length > 1 ?
    keyPath :
    null;
}

function deleteRoom(state, room) {
  var roomPath = findRoomPath(state, room);
  return (roomPath) ?
    state.deleteIn(roomPath) :
    state;
}


console.log(deleteRoom(state, 101).toJS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.1/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can you use `filter` for rooms instead of `map`?

Answer (score 0):

I must say, I'm not too experienced with Immutable, but this is somewhat clean. I would strongly advise you to reconsider the structure of your state! You will save yourself from a lot of pain down the road!

```
export default function list(state = initialState, {type, payload}) {
    switch (type) {
        //remove some room
        case REMOVE_ROOM:
            return removeRoom(state, payload);
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

const removeRoom (state, roomToRemove) => {
  const floor = state.get('floor').map(floor => {
    const rooms = floor.get('rooms').filter(room => room.get('room') !== roomToRemove)
    return floor.merge({rooms});
  })
  return state.merge({floor});
};
```